# Zipforge Invalid Archive Error message

Tags: c#

In my Preclose.cs file, there is a part of code:

```
clientIds.ForEach(i =>
{
   var tempDirectory = Path.GetTempPath() + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + "\\";
   if (!FileSystem.DirectoryExists(tempDirectory))
      FileSystem.CreateDirectory(tempDirectory);

   var baseDirectory = KnownAliases.Replace(@"\\MASTER_PATH\ftp\ClientUDB\");
   var reportDirectory = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, i, "PreClose");
   var reportArchive = Path.Combine(reportDirectory, "Archive");

   var zipArchive = new ZipForge();
   zipArchive.BaseDir = Path.GetTempPath();
   zipArchive.InMemory = false;
   zipArchive.FileName = String.Format("{0}{1}_{2}.zip", zipArchive.BaseDir, base.ProcessName.Replace(" ", "_"), DateTime.Now.Ticks);
   zipArchive.OpenArchive(FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
   System.Net.Mail.MailMessage confirmationMsg = null;
   ...
}
```

Basically Preclose will be run on my server, recently I got a lot of "Invalid archive files" error messages in my server's error log. Below is the stack trace for it:

```
at ComponentAce.Compression.Archiver.DirManager.BuildCentralDirByLocalHeaders (Byte[]& buf)   
at ComponentAce.Compression.Archiver.DirManager.LoadDir()   
at ComponentAce.Compression.Archiver.BaseArchiver.InternalOpenArchive()   
at D2L.AutoProc.Service.Library.PreClose.<Execute>b__1(String i) in d:\Builds\136\Development\Aps\Sources\Trunk\Applications\Aps\D2L.AutoProc.Service.Library\PreClose.cs:line 54     
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.ForEach(Action`1 action)   
at D2L.AutoProc.Service.Library.PreClose.Execute() in d:\Builds\136\Development\Aps\Sources\Trunk\Applications\Aps\D2L.AutoProc.Service.Library\PreClose.cs:line 40
```

Line 54 is the "zipArchive.OpenArchive(FileMode.OpenOrCreate);" line in my preclose file.
Any ideas guys?

Some more information:
Preclose will be run on different servers, so it's possible that two servers run this part of code at the same time.

Comment: Are you zipping a file here? I think that the FileMode should be just Create.

Comment: @TheShaman, I think you got a point, however, I am not sure if that would make a big difference. I mean, openOrCreate will do the same thing if there's no zip file there, is that correct?